# Como utilizar função de concatenar em arquivo JSP

Tags: jsp

Boa tarde.

Possuo uma consulta SQL com 3 clausulas where, mas preciso ativa-las apenas quando os valores estiverem preenchidos.

Como posso fazer para o arquivo jsp reconhecer que por exemplo o campo 1 está preenchido, então concatena o primeiro where, se estiver preenchido os campos 1 e 3, concatena o 1º where e o 3º e assim sucessivamente?

```
SELECT DISTINCT DECODE (initcap(PP.OVERALL_HEALTH), '', '/itg/images/statusreport/NA.gif', '/itg/images/statusreport/'   || DECODE(UPPER(PP.OVERALL_HEALTH), 'GREEN', 'Verde', initcap(PP.OVERALL_HEALTH))   || '.gif' ) SAUDE_PROGRAMA_ICONE, PP.CONTAINER_NAME NOME_PROGRAMA, HD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER1 TIPO_CLIENTE, HD.VISIBLE_PARAMETER32 DIRETOR
FROM PGM_PROGRAMS PP
INNER JOIN KCRT_REQ_HEADER_DETAILS HD ON HD.REQUEST_ID = PP.PGM_REQUEST_ID
INNER JOIN KCRT_FG_PFM_PROGRAM FP ON FP.REQUEST_ID = PP.PGM_REQUEST_ID
INNER JOIN FM_FINANCIAL_SUMMARY FS ON PP.FINANCIAL_SUMMARY_ID = FS.FINANCIAL_SUMMARY_ID
INNER JOIN PFM_PORTFOLIO_CONTENTS PC ON FS.FINANCIAL_SUMMARY_ID = PC.FINANCIAL_SUMMARY_ID
INNER JOIN PFM_PORTFOLIOS P ON PC.PORTFOLIO_ID = P.PORTFOLIO_ID
WHERE HD.PARAMETER1 = '<c:out value="${TIPO_CLIENTE}" />'
AND HD.PARAMETER32 = '<c:out value="${DIRETOR}" />'
AND P.NAME IN (select p.name as portfolio from pfm_portfolios p
start with p.portfolio_id in '<c:out value="${nome1.PORTFOLIO_ID}" />' 
connect by prior p.portfolio_id = p.parent_portfolio_id)
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Você pode tentar identificar quais campos estão preenchidos antes de realizar a consulta, dependendo de quais campos estão preenchidos, você monta sua consulta.

Comment: Bom dia. Na prática, como seria isso? Pois precisa ser dinâmico, sempre terá disponível para preencher dois campos, mas não necessariamente eles estarão preenchidos, mas o arquivo que utilizo seria um só.

Comment: Você pode utilizar um IF verificando se a variavel esta fazia

if(variavel1.isEmpty() && variavel2.isEmpty()){
//instrucoes caso as duas forem varias
}

so fazer as comparacoes, e dependendo do resultado voce executa uma sql diferente